# polyfills.js angular error : Promise rejection: NullInjectorError: No provider for Re! ; Zone: <root> ;

Tags: angular, polyfills, boilerplate

Recently I upgraded my boilerplate frame work angular project(all Modules) to the last version.
but after run "ng serve" i get below error in the picture
[image]

and this my account.module.ts:
[image]

I deleted my node-module folder and ran "npm install" again but still I get this error